# Including notebook in sphinx documentation

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx, nbsphinx

I am trying to include notebook in sphinx documentation. I installed nbsphinx.

But when I do make html, the following error appears

make html
Running Sphinx v5.3.0

`Extension error: Could not import extension nbsphinx (exception: cannot import name 'ensure_async' from 'jupyter_core.utils' (C:\Users\xxxx\anaconda3\envs\xxxx\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\utils\__init__.py))`

Suggestions on how to fix this will be really helpful.

Comment: It's likely a version conflict between different versions of Python packages you have installed.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Could you please suggest how to check what's incompatible?

Comment: I am not an expert on Anaconda. You need to refer to Anaconda community how to check package versions and then read the respective release notes of those packages to try to find a clue.

Comment: I would suggest to build your documentation on a isolated venv/conda with only the needed libs installed. It's better to mimic what's happening on prod servers and avoid this kind of bugs